# ubuntu installing l3kernel and l3packages

Tags: installing, expl3, latex3

I apologize for this very basic question.      I've downloaded the current versions of  l3kernel.zip and l3packages.zip, but have no idea how to install them.      As far as I can tell, there is no information in the zip files about how to do this.    Could anybody advise please?

Comment: What files exactly have you downloaded? The easiest "manual" installation would probably be to get the .tds.zip file such as listed under TDS archive here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel . But usually I'd recommend installing TeX Live and using its package manager.

Comment: My answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183067/problems-installing-xpatch covers much of this: is that at all helpful?

Comment: Thanks very much Joseph, update went smoothly and was amazingly easy.    For the benefit of anybody else in my position, you have to run texhash after unzipping the files.