# media9 error: "support outdated", Support package l3kernel too old

Tags: installing

My OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

I have been learning Asymptote, and when I try to output a 3D image as a pdf I consistently get the error message in the title of this post. I dug around and I guess it is a `MikTex 2.9` issue.

I tried downloading `media9`, `l3kernel`, and `l3packages` from CTAN. The installation instructions in the pdf that comes with media9 say to put the `media9` folder in the local TDS directory, which they tell you how to find, and then to update the filename database by typing `texhash` in the command line. I cannot find any installation instructions for `l3kernel` or `l3packages` - I tried just doing the same thing with them that the `media9` instructions said to do for it, but that's obviously just a guess. So far, nothing has made any difference whatsoever.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

---

```
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
Package: media9 2014/06/25 v0.45 acrobat-9/X compatible media


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! media9 error: "support outdated"
! 
! Support package l3kernel too old.
! 
! See the media9 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.75 }

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| Please install an up to date version of l3kernel.
| Loading media9 will abort!
|...............................................

)

! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `bigfiles' for package `media9'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

<*> \newif
          \ifplaybutton

The option `bigfiles' was not declared in package `media9', perhaps you
misspelled its name. Try typing  <return>  to proceed.


*\count255=\the\catcode`\@\makeatletter%

*\@ifpackagelater{media9}{2013/11/15}{}{\playbuttontrue}%

*\catcode`\@=\the\count255

*%

*\def\ASYprefix{}

*\newbox\ASYbox
\ASYbox=\box51

*\newdimen\ASYdimen
\ASYdimen=\dimen182

*\long\def\ASYbase#1#2{\leavevmode\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#1}%\ASYdimen=\ht\ASYbox
%

*\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{#2}\lower\ASYdimen\box\ASYbox}

*\usepackage{graphicx}

*\begin{document}
No file texput.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 0.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box52
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 0.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2010/04/30 v2.40 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count195
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 0.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 0.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 0.
\@outlinefile=\write4


Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
*\makeatletter%

*\let\ASYencoding\f@encoding%

*\let\ASYfamily\f@family%

*\let\ASYseries\f@series%

*\let\ASYshape\f@shape%

*\makeatother%

*\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont

*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*\usefont{\ASYencoding}{\ASYfamily}{\ASYseries}{\ASYshape}%

*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*\setbox\ASYbox=\hbox{%

*\ifplaybutton%

*\includemedia[3Dlights=Headlamp,3Dmenu,activate=pagevisible,3Dtoolbar=true,lab
el=,3Daac=16.961886281,3Dc2w=0.624695048 -0.780868809 0 -0.232810099 -0.1862480
79 0.954521404 -0.745355992 -0.596284794 -0.298142397 211.301305888 178.6528737
41 65.497472713,3Droo=283.550260095,3Dpsob=H,3Dbg=1 1 1,add3Djscript=asylabels.
js,width=39.14625pt,height=107.40125pt]{}{09_three+0.prc}%

*\else%

*\includemedia[noplaybutton,3Dlights=Headlamp,3Dmenu,activate=pagevisible,3Dtoo
lbar=true,label=,3Daac=16.961886281,3Dc2w=0.624695048 -0.780868809 0 -0.2328100
99 -0.186248079 0.954521404 -0.745355992 -0.596284794 -0.298142397 211.30130588
8 178.652873741 65.497472713,3Droo=283.550260095,3Dpsob=H,3Dbg=1 1 1,add3Djscri
pt=asylabels.js,width=39.14625pt,height=107.40125pt]{}{09_three+0.prc}%
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \includemedia
                 [noplaybutton,3Dlights=Headlamp,3Dmenu,activate=pagevisible...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<*> ...,width=39.14625pt,height=107.40125pt]{}{09_
                                                  three+0.prc}%
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 0.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 0.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<*> ...625pt,height=107.4012
```

Comment: We are going to need to see a log file here: almost certainly the wrong files are being loaded.

Comment: Also, what TeX system are you using (MiKTeX, TeX Live, ...)? Recent/up-to-date ones should all have the appropriate files.

Comment: Do the instruction in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183067/problems-installing-xpatch/183072#183072 give any help? For MiKTeX the local tree is in a different place: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for the response,

I am using MikTeX. I am looking into the sites you mentioned. It sounds like my easiest option might be to simply update MikTeX. I will attach the log.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Joseph,

I'm new to using stackexchange, wasn't sure how to attach the whole log, so I entered the part of the log which I think is relevant.

Thanks again.

Comment: Your log-file doesn't show the location of the l3-files. If they are in your user profile you must run the update manager in user mode.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working as folows:

1. Uninstalled MikTeX 2.9
2. Reinstalled MikTeX 2.9, for my user account only. I did it for my user account only because a post on a forum I found while digging around suggested this. It is possible that this still would have worked if I had installed MikTeX 2.9 for all users.
3. When I ran it, I received an "access is denied" error. I got around this based on advice from [Windows API error 5: "Access is denied" when trying to compile TikZ picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51799/windows-api-error-5-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-compile-tikz-picture), by right-clicking on MikTeX 2.9 in Program Files, then clicking Properties > Security > Edit and granting a bunch of permissions.
4. I ran it again, and this time it worked.

Nowhere in the above steps did I end up needing to do anything manually with media9, l3kernel, or l3packages.

Thanks very much again for the help Joseph, as well as for fixing my breach of site procedure earlier.